# BlackBerry "symbol integer.valueof not found" error when starting app on simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Not sure what happened here, I added some new code and now I'm getting this error when trying to run the app on the BlackBerry simulator from Eclipse.

From the console:

```
[0.0] Starting MyApp
[0.0] Symbol 'Integer.valueOf' not found.[0.0] Error starting MyApp: Symbol 'Integer.valueOf' not found.
```

This appears both in the debugger and on-screen as a popup with an "OK" button.

```
Thread [net_rim_bb_ribbon_app(83)id=384704512] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
    ApplicationEntryPoint.run() line: 309   
    ApplicationEntry.invoke() line: 503 
    RibbonLauncherImpl.launch(ApplicationEntry) line: 1950  
    RibbonLauncherImpl.launch() line: 1935  
    ApplicationMenu.trackwheelClick(int, int) line: 874 
    ApplicationMenu.navigationClick(int, int) line: 885 
    ApplicationMenu(Screen).dispatchNavigationEvent(int, int, int, int, int) line: 678  
    UiEngineImpl.processMessage(Object, Message, boolean) line: 1612    
    RibbonLauncherApp(Application).processNextMessage(Message) line: 1701   
    RibbonLauncherApp(Application).enterEventDispatcher() line: 986 
    RibbonLauncherApp.main(String[]) line: 87
```

Any help at all? I can't think of anything which I changed to cause this to happen. Another app runs perfectly ok. Many thanks.

Comment: Which jde version you are using.

Comment: i think so of type casting error. once check that caused line for this exception. let me know that particular caused line farther assistance please visit this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Comment: Could you search all Integer.valueOf in app. I suppose you used Integer.valueOf(int i) which is not available in BB.

Comment: Hello fellow, thanks for your replies. I could not find anywhere that I had used Integer.valueOf. In the end I just created a new Eclipse project and copied the files over. That fixed whatever the issue was. Computers are weird :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find anywhere that I had used Integer.valueOf. In the end I just created a new Eclipse project and copied the files over. That fixed whatever the issue was.

If you have a similar issue and don't know what to do then try that! :P

Sorry I cannot be of more help!